# SSL Certificate to connect Salesforce to SAP B1IF and SAP Service Layer

Tags: integration, security, httprequest, sap

I would like your help to understand a little bit how HTTPS and SSL certificates works. I have a Salesforce org that needs to connect to SAP Business One Integration Framework (SAP B1IF that runw on Windows-Tomcat) by https and to the SAP Service Layer (That runs in Linux-Apache) by https as well. Both services works perfect from inside the network. To make it available from outside (Salesforce) I have a vpn in godaddy that is routing to our external IP address and the router is doing the redirect, port 8443 will go to B1IF and port 50000 will go to Service Layer.

However, I have follow the normal steps recommended by Godaddy (https://au.godaddy.com/help/tomcat-generate-csrs-and-install-certificates-5239) but it does not works, I'm still getting that I don't have a certificate.

I would like your help to understand briefly what I have to do to put a SSL internally in SAP B1IF (https://192.168.1.4:8443) and SAP Service Layer (https://192.168.1.5:50000) but make them available from outside (https://vpn.mycompany:8443 and https://vpn.mycompany:50000).

Any help or recomendation will be much appreciate it as at the moment if I test the connection from Salesforce it rejects the connection as is not secured.